# Don't have permissions to view images

Tags: image, permissions, xampp, localhost, http-status-code-403

I'm running a project on my local web server, but by some reason I can't view the images (put in 'img/'). I have tried to change folder, but it's the same thing, so I suppose it's related to the actual images.

What can I do to solve this?

*Note:* I read somewhere about changing a .htaccess file, but I don't seem to have that file.

*Note 2:* I'm on Mac OS

```
'You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.'

Error 403

localhost
Wed Oct 31 14:15:57 2012
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Comment: How do you try to read the images? By putting the /img to your browser or by pointing to them in HTML?

Comment: I have tried both putting in the img in HTML and to reach them through directly through the url, same thing. I am sure it's the correct address because it actually worked before, at least on one image that was in the same folder.

Comment: Did you try CHMOD those files to 644 ? (Owner can read and write, others can read). Especially, you have to check the properties of file on server

Comment: Where can I do this? Unfortunately I have no knowledge at all where to do this.

Comment: I wrote it as answer. Try the permissions and let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words HTTP status code 403 means Forbidden..which means that you do not have sufficient privileges/access-rights to perform the desired operation which in this case is reading images from the *img* folder..

You don't require *.htaccess* in this case..you need to check directory permissions for your *img* folder and set them to *755(-rwxr-xr-x)*..as you are on Mac, you may go through [Mac OS X knowledge-base article on Troubleshooting permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963) to understand how you can setup directory permissions for Mac..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is my honest guess, what you should do:

- I Assume that you are using some sort of FTP program to get those files to the server

In that program, navigate to the folder, where the files are stored and check for properties of such file. Here is example from webFTP access to my site:
[image: Files overview]

If the "Perms" are different, you have to change them - mostly its done by linux command "CHMOD" (because most of web servers run on linux). I dont know what sort of FTP program are you using, but mostly its done by right click -> Properties.

For further idea about this try googling "how to chmod files in X" where X is name of your FTP program.

Then, you have to make sure, that file properties are set up like this:
[image: properties of file]

In general - others and group have the read rights